# Como unir esses 2 SELECT em uma mesma query

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Bom dia, eu estou refazendo a pergunta pois a ultima eu apaguei pois ficou um pouco confusa.

Tenho esses dois select e gostaria de unir eles para retornar o resultado para um gráfico de comparação.

**Esse SELECT consulta e me retorna o numero de manutenções que teve por mes**

```
SELECT
DATE(MAN.relManu_data_registro) AS DATA,
count(MAN.relManu_id) AS TOTAL_MAN

FROM tb_relatorio_manutencao AS MAN


WHERE
MAN.relManu_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 MONTH))

GROUP BY DAY(MAN.relManu_data_registro) ORDER BY MAN.relManu_data_registro ASC
```

**Esse SELECT consulta e me retorna o numero de ligações que teve por mes**

```
  SELECT
  DATE(LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) AS DATA,
  count(LIG.ligacoes_id) AS TOTAL_LIG

  FROM tb_relatorio_ligacoes AS LIG


   WHERE
   LIG.ligacoes_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 YEAR)) AND
   LIG.ligacoes_assunto >= suporte

   GROUP BY MONTH(LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) 

   ORDER BY LIG.ligacoes_data_registro ASC
```

Então, no primeio select eu seleciono os manutenções e conto quantas teve no mês, no segundo eu consulto outra tabela e obtenho quantas ligações para o suporte teve por mes.

Queria juntar essas consultas para ficar na mesma linha a informação da DATA MÊS, CONTAGEM DE LIGAÇÃO, CONTAGEM DE SUPORTE para comparar em um gráfico.

Comment: adiciona a estrutura das tabelas a sua questão. Outra coisa existe alguma foreign key qye ligue as tabelas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma Outra solução seria criar temporarias e depois fazer o terceiro select urnindo elas

```
SELECT
DATE(MAN.relManu_data_registro) AS DATA,
count(MAN.relManu_id) AS TOTAL_MAN

INTO #TEMP1
FROM tb_relatorio_manutencao AS MAN


WHERE
MAN.relManu_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 MONTH))

GROUP BY DAY(MAN.relManu_data_registro) ORDER BY MAN.relManu_data_registro ASC


SELECT
DATE(LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) AS DATA,
count(LIG.ligacoes_id) AS TOTAL_LIG

INTO #TEMP2
FROM tb_relatorio_ligacoes AS LIG


WHERE
LIG.ligacoes_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 YEAR)) AND
LIG.ligacoes_assunto >= suporte

GROUP BY MONTH(LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) 

ORDER BY LIG.ligacoes_data_registro ASC

select * from #TEMP1 CROSS JOIN #TEMP2
```

Answer (score 0):

Fale @Douglas, uma possível solução seria por subquery:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(BASE.relManu_data_registro) AS DATA,

    (SELECT 
         count(MAN.relManu_id) 
     FROM 
         tb_relatorio_manutencao AS MAN
     WHERE 
         MAN.relManu_data_registro = BASE.relManu_data_registro
     AND 
         MAN.relManu_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 MONTH))
     GROUP BY 
         MAN.relManu_data_registro)
     AS TOTAL_MAN,

    (SELECT 
         count(LIG.ligacoes_id) 
     FROM 
         tb_relatorio_ligacoes AS LIG
     WHERE 
         DATE(LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) = DATE(BASE.relManu_data_registro) 
     AND 
         LIG.ligacoes_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 YEAR)) 
     AND 
         LIG.ligacoes_assunto >= suporte
     GROUP BY 
         LIG.ligacoes_data_registro) 
AS TOTAL_LIG
FROM 
    tb_relatorio_manutencao AS BASE
WHERE 
    BASE.relManu_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: Bom dia, eu tentei com esta solução e ele me retornou "[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Verdade! Deu esse erro porque deixei duas condições para as datas nas subqueries. A intenção era que o resultado fosse o count das datas iguais ao BASE.relManu_data_registro.

Então remove das 2 subqueries esses trechos: 

AND 
         MAN.relManu_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 MONTH)) 

e 

 AND 
         LIG.ligacoes_data_registro >= DATE(date_sub(now(), interval 1 YEAR))